# How do I escape ampersands in batch files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping, ampersand

How do I escape ampersands in a batch file (or from the 
Windows command line) in order to use the `start` command to 
open web pages with ampersands in the URL?

Double quotes will not work with `start`; this starts a new 
command-line window instead.

**Update 1**: Wael Dalloul's solution works. In addition, if 
there are URL encoded characters (e.g. space is encoded as 
%20) in the URL and *it is in a batch file* then '%' must be 
encoded as '%%'. This is not the case in the example.

Example, from the command line (`CMD.EXE`):

```
start http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=escape+ampersand&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8
```

will result in

```
http://www.google.com/search?client=opera
```

being opened in the default browser and these errors in the command line window:

```
'rls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'q' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'sourceid' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'ie' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'oe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Platform: Windows XP 64 bit SP2.

Comment: I've edited belugabob's answer so it should work now. It's just a quirk in `start` which causes quoting the argument to fail if applied without thought. And overall I think enclosing the argument in quotes is easier and less error-prone than to escape every character that needs escaping in there.

Comment: What about plus sign `+` what should I put in front to escape it?

Comment: In PowerShell `start "http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=escape+ampersand&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"` works because [PowerShell will strip quotes out](https://superuser.com/a/1208974/241386)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

**From a cmd**:

- `&` is escaped like this: `^&` (based on @Wael Dalloul's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327476/700926))
- `%` does not need to be escaped

An example:

```
start http://www.google.com/search?client=opera^&rls=en^&q=escape+ampersand%20and%20percentage+in+cmd^&sourceid=opera^&ie=utf-8^&oe=utf-8
```

**From a batch file**

- `&` is escaped like this: `^&` (based on @Wael Dalloul's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327476/700926))
- `%` is escaped like this: `%%` (based on the OPs update)

An example:

```
start http://www.google.com/search?client=opera^&rls=en^&q=escape+ampersand%%20and%%20percentage+in+batch+file^&sourceid=opera^&ie=utf-8^&oe=utf-8
```

Comment: It could also include an example of escaping "%" - then I can clean up my question.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Definitely - I have updated my answer.

Comment: Which characters should I also escape? I noticed that I have to escape "|" by "^|".

Comment: In this case `%` does not need to be escaped, because who would be silly enough to define `20and` as an environment variable? If you did, `start http://www.google.com/search?q=ampersand%20and%20percentage` could link to`http://www.google.com/search?q=ampersandsomething-silly20percentage` instead. Using `^%` to escape in cmd, the example works as expected.

Answer (score 167):

`&` is used to separate commands. Therefore you can use `^` to escape the `&`.

Comment: What about plus sign `+` what should I put in front to escape it?

Comment: This is the more general applicable solution. It also works if a parameter of a command-line program has one or more ampersands in it. I just encountered this - the parameter was *CGW5COMM&10C4&8301*.

Comment: Quoting an ampersand with the caret character ^ doesn't seem to work in all circumstances.  For example, attempting to execute msdeploy.exe with the /p: switch to pass a password with an ampersand doesn't seem to work with any permutation I've tried (caret quote, double quotes, dummy first argument).

Comment: An example of using `^` would be invaluable.

Comment: @jpmc26 I have added an example [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27960888/700926).

Comment: A more general treatment of this subject is in *[A Better Way To Understand Quoting and Escaping of Windows Command Line Arguments](http://www.windowsinspired.com/understanding-the-command-line-string-and-arguments-received-by-a-windows-program/)*, *[How a Windows Program Splits Its Command Line Into Individual Arguments](http://www.windowsinspired.com/how-a-windows-programs-splits-its-command-line-into-individual-arguments/)*, and *[How Command Line Parameters Are Parsed](http://daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm)*.

Comment: E.g from the second source: *"The way cmd.exe interprets the command line is different and completely independent of how an executable program interprets the command line."*

Comment: `^` does not work for escaping `%`. Use `%` instead: `%%`

Comment: @PeterMortensen the recaptcha link in your profile is dead

Answer (score 34):

You can enclose it in quotes, if you supply a dummy first argument.

Note that you need to supply a dummy first argument in this case, as `start` will treat the first argument as a title for the new console windows, if it is quoted. So the following should work (and does here):

```
start "" "http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=escape+ampersand&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"
```

Comment: OK, I will admit the title does not completely match the question inside. (Do you think I should make the title longer?)

Comment: Not so 'Doh', after all - enclosing in quotes was the right idea - just didn't know about the console window title thing.
Thanks Johannes!

Comment: [PowerShell will strip quotes from the arguments](https://superuser.com/a/1208974/241386), so this will fail. You need to use only `start "http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=escape+ampersand&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"` on PowerShell

Answer (score 21):

```
explorer "http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=...."
```

Answer (score 18):

The command

```
echo this ^& that
```

works as expected, outputing

```
this & that
```

The command

```
echo this ^& that > tmp
```

also works, writing the string to file "tmp".  However, before a pipe

```
echo this ^& that | clip
```

the ^ is interpreted completely differently.  It tries to write the output of the two commands "echo this" and "that" to the pipe.  The echo will work then "that" will give an error.  Saying

```
echo this ^& echo that | clip
```

will put the strings "this" and "that" on the clipboard.

Without the ^:

```
echo this & echo that | clip
```

the first echo will write to the console and only the second echo's output will be piped to clip (similarly for "> tmp" redirection).  So, when output is being redirected, the ^ does not quote the & but instead causes it to be applied before the redirection rather than after.

To pipe an &, you have to quote it twice

```
echo this ^^^& that | clip
```

If you put the string in a variable

```
set m=this ^& that
```

then

```
set m
```

will output

```
m=this & that
```

but the obvious

```
echo %m%
```

fails because, after Windows substitutes the variable, resulting in

```
echo this & that
```

it parses this as a new command and tries to execute "that".

In a batch file, you can use *delayed expansion*:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !m!
```

To output to a pipe, we have to replace all &s in the variable value with ^&, which we can do with the %VAR:FROM=TO% syntax:

```
echo !m:^&=^^^&! | clip
```

On the command line, "cmd /v" enables delayed expansion:

```
cmd /v /c echo !m!
```

This works even when writing to a pipe

```
cmd /v /c echo !m! | clip
```

Simple.

Comment: Your solution for pipes works, but your conclusions are more or less wrong. Btw. a simple `echo this ^^^& that | clip` works too. To understand the magic pipe handling you could read [SO: Why does delayed expansion fail when inside a piped block of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/463115)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to `echo` a string that contains an ampersand, quotes won't help, because you would see them on the output as well. In such a case, use `for`:

```
for %a in ("First & Last") do echo %~a
```

...in a batch script:

```
for %%a in ("First & Last") do echo %%~a
```

or

```
for %%a in ("%~1") do echo %%~a
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* you have spaces in the name of the file *and* you have a character you need to escape:

You can use single AND double quotes to avoid any misnomers in the command.

```
scp ./'files name with spaces/internal folder with spaces/"text & files stored.txt"' .
```

The `^` character escapes the quotes otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

For special characters like '&' you can surround the entire expression with quotation marks

`set "url=https://url?retry=true&w=majority"`

Comment: Not my downvote, but this seems to duplicate a couple of older answers, both with more details and explanations.