# How to open a URL with GET query parameters using the command line in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I escape ampersands in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327431/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-batch-files)

I am attempting the following, in Windows:

```
 $ start http://code.google.com/p/mulder/downloads/detail?name=MPUI.2011-06-09.Full-Package.exe&can=2&q=MPlayer&sort=-uploaded
```

Unfortunately, it seems that no amount of quoting or escaping actually pulls up the full URL in a browser, only partial (up through can=2) or what not. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ^ to escape & in teh command line like this:

```
 $ start http://code.google.com/p/mulder/downloads/detail?name=MPUI.2011-06-09.Full-Package.exe^&can=26^&q=MPlayer^&sort=-uploaded
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
start "test" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://code.google.com/p/mulder/downloads/detail?name=MPUI.2011-06-09.Full-Package.exe&can=2&q=MPlayer&sort=-uploaded"
```

It worked for me in Windows 7. (all on one line).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Fascinatingly, this works too. start "x" "http://code.google.com/p/mulder/downloads/detail?name=MPUI.2011-06-09.Full-Package.exe&can=2&q=MPlayer&sort=-uploaded" without requiring any escaping. weird!

Comment: This way worked too!