# Escape percent in bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping

I was trying to write a VPN dialer/disconnector using a batch file, but I got stuck. After some investigation I found that the presence of `%` in the password is not playing well.

Here is the code

```
@echo OFF
SET SWITCHPARSE1=%1
SET SWITCHPARSE2=%2
REM echo %SWITCHPARSE1%
SHIFT
SHIFT
IF "SWITCHPARSE1" == "" goto Usage
IF "SWITCHPARSE1" == "/?" goto Usage
IF "SWITCHPARSE2" == "" goto Usage
IF "SWITCHPARSE2" == "/?" goto Usage


IF "%SWITCHPARSE1%" == "sl" (
    IF "%SWITCHPARSE2%" == "conn" (
        echo "inside sl conn"
        rasdial sl employee1 K%%Pxev3=)g:{#Swc9
        goto end
    ) ELSE IF "%SWITCHPARSE2%" == "disconn" (
        rasdial sl /disconnect
        goto end
    ) ELSE (
        goto Usage
    )
) ELSE IF "%SWITCHPARSE1%" == "off" (
        IF "%SWITCHPARSE2%" == "conn" (
        rasdial Office employee1 office123
        goto end
    ) ELSE IF "%SWITCHPARSE2%" == "disconn" (
        rasdial Office /disconnect
        goto end
    ) ELSE (
        goto Usage
    )
) ELSE (
    goto Usage
)

:Usage
echo "Usage is vpnconn.bat /[sl|off] /[conn|disconn]"

:end
```

In the above script I am trying to escape `%` using `%` (i.e. `%%`, reference from [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)), but the bat script gives **g:{#Swc9 was unexpected at this time.**.

To root cause further, I tried to double `%%` (escape `%`) in a different batch file, and it worked:

```
@echo OFF
rasdial sl employee1 K%%Pxev3=)g:{#Swc9
```

Why does the same script when integrated to work with different connections not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do I escape ampersands in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327431/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-batch-files)*

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Two **%%** equals to one **%**. That's right (but only in a script, not directly in the cmd), no need to use the escape operator **^**.

But you are missing the agrupation operator **)**. That's the problem; the IF closes when it finds the **)** at your command.

Use this:

```
rasdial sl employee1 K%%%%Pxev3=^)g:{#Swc9
```

Comment: That was really cool. Missed the presence of ')' in the password. Should start writing more batch scripts. :) Thanks