# Visual Studio 2012 Post Build Events - Error Code 255

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, post-build-event

Here is my attempt to copy my application executable to another folder changing it's name:

```
IF $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
    SET DESTINATION=$(ProjectDir)Output\Distribution

    IF NOT EXIST "%DESTINATION%" ( MD "%DESTINATION%" )

    XCOPY /Q /Y "$(TargetPath)" "%DESTINATION%"
    RENAME "%DESTINATION%\$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetName).Plain$(TargetExt)"
)
```

I've tried everything to make it work, but it always throw error code 255 or 1, it depends. Running that code with a plain batch file works like a charm!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable *delayed expansion*, using the **SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion** command. Do it at the top of the post-build event. After that, you can access your variable by using not %VARIABLE_NAME%, but !VARIABLE_NAME! (use an exclamation symbol on either side of the variable name, not the percentage symbol which you would use in a regular batch file).

So, for example

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
IF $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
    SET DESTINATION=$(ProjectDir)Output\Distribution
    echo My destination dir is !DESTINATION!
)
```

This will output something like

```
My destination dir is D:\Work\Projects\PBExample\Output\Distribution.
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the Post-build event command line actually runs as a batch file you need to escape characters like % by doubling them to %%:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13552702/74585