# Add custom variable to post event script in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

I'm tryin to add a post build event to my project to copy headers and libraries in another folder but I don't know how to set custom variables to my script:

```
set DEST=$(MY_LIBRARY_PATH)
xcopy $(SolutionDir)source\include\.h $(DEST)
```

where MY_LIBRARY_PATH is an enviorment variable I've looked at this link but it doesn't solve the problem [Visual Studio 2012 Post Build Events - Error Code 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660187/visual-studio-2012-post-build-events-error-code-255)

So how can I set a custom enviorment variable?

Comment: To clarify this: Which one is the environment variable that you'd like to define? DEST or MY_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: MY_LIBRARY_PATH is arleady defined, DEST is the variable I want to define

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a batch file "PostBuild.bat" and pass the paths to the batch file

PostBuild Event: Command line = `call PostBuild.bat "$(SolutionDir)" "$(MY_LIBRARY_PATH)"`

PostBuild.bat:
`xcopy %1source\include\.h %2`

Comment: @elvis.dukaj: we do more things in our PostBuild.bat (like DotFuscating the built exe, signing the Dotfuscated exe, copying the necessary files to our setup folders, etc)