# CMD/windows Batch: how to pass a double quote and a larger than sign in a command argument?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd, arguments

I can pass a double quote, and a larger than sign to any command in several ways: `'"'`, `"\""`, `">"`

But when i try to pass them together

```
C:\>echo "\">"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Same with `"\"\>"`. I could make it work with single quotes around, but since i already have so much going on with dealing with quotes i'd like to keep it all inside double quotes.

Is there any way to escape that?

I'm on windows7 but i believe this is some backward compatibility 'feature', so not sure this info is relevant.

Edit 1:

I tought Endoro had the right answer... but it's not that simple. CMD treats `^>` differently depending if there's a escaped double quote in the string. Anyone have any idea why?! or a different escaping method?

```
C:\>sh echo "\"^>"
">

C:\>sh echo "a^>"
a^>

C:\>echo "\"^>"
"\">"

C:\>echo "a^>"
"a^>"
```

Edit 2:
here are the tests cases for what Monacraft suggested, using `^` before the quotes that go around the string

```
C:\>echo ^"a/>"
The system cannot find the path specified.
(we still need to escape that > symbol)

C:\>echo ^"a/^>"
"a/>"
(work fine without \" in the string)

C:\>echo ^"\"/^>"
"\"/^>"
(add a single \" and the ^> escaping stop to works)

C:\>echo ^""/^>"
""/^>"
(ok, using ^ before the string means i dont have to escape the " anymore)

C:\>echo ^"^\"/^>"
"\"/^>"
(but what if i have an actual \" in my input that i have to escape... would ^\ prevent this from happening? nope)
```

Comment: @Endoro sorry, i really thought it was the right answer until i added more tests and saw what i mention on the edit. I even started to write a new question, but i was pretty much the same question as before. I didn't take it light  as well... sorry if it offended.

Comment: [Escaping characters like ", <, >, >>, or | in the arguments to a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32414436/995714), [Batch character escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6828751/995714), [Escape percent in bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13551829/995714), [Escape special character in a windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32817929/995714), [Special Characters in Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37333620/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I can't give you a full explanation, but if you put an escape character before the double quotes it works:

```
C:\>echo "a^>"
"a^>"

C:\>echo ^"a^>"
"a>"
```

I think by putting a `^` before the string, your telling cmd not to treat a `^` inside the string as part of the actual string. Which is why:

```
C:\>echo "text^>" ^"text^>"
"text^>" "text>"
```

Does that. However, I can't give you a full explanation, but at least that solves your problem.

#### Edit 2:

Ok, for edit 2 All I can say is that you don't need to escape anything inside the string!

```
C:\>echo ^"\"/>"
"\"/>"
```

Also found this website which explained that to escape a `\` all you need is `\\`. [Click here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) for more Information. For `"` simply double up the quotes (`""`).

Comment: this made it even more confusing :)  adding `\"` still breaks it. Will add the test cases to the question.

Comment: awesome link! i was trying to find something like this in msdn with no luck! Thanks

Comment: About not escaping, remember that i must use the same pattern for any input the user trhows at me. So no escaping for `\"` means i will get an error when there is no `\"` but a `>`. See the 1st example on my edit2.

Comment: but then it does not work with your 1st example `echo ^"\"/^>"` :) there's no way to programatically encode strings that you don't know the content. unless you write a parser. which is what i did as a work around, but i want to remove that. I think the link you send is the solution. i will just have to encode `"` as `""`... let's see. will work on that again in a while.

Comment: Ok, if you have more questions we can move this to a StackChat conversation. I'll update you if I find anyother information.

Comment: Accepting this as I guess this is the best it can get. lesson: do not try to pass anything other than simple ascii strings in CMD.