# Escape special character in a windows batch

Tags: batch-file, special-characters

I have a batch file that receive a path as first argument. The path is always composed with specials characters like `^`,`é` or `è`.

The call is similar to this

```
D:\Script>MyBatch My\path\test_00170_LASTNAME^Firstname\image
```

There is always this error: unknown specified path

When I echo the first argument in my bash I can see (notice the missing `^`)

```
My\path\test_00170_LASTNAMEFirstname\image
```

So I tried to escape this character by adding another `^` just before

```
My\path\test_00170_LASTNAME^^Firstname\image
```

But when I echo this one, I have the same result ...

```
My\path\test_00170_LASTNAMEFirstname\image
```

I also tried to put the `^` between quotes but this did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the caret signs at the command line or better put the path into quotes.

In both cases you should work with delayed expansion, as then the content will not be modified when it is expanded.

```
myBatch "C:\LASTNAME^Firstname\image"
```

or

```
myBatch C:\LASTNAME^^Firstname\image
```

And in your batch use swomething like this

```
@echo off
set "arg1=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !arg1!
```

Comment: Got it but in fact in use `cd /d !arg1!` and when I `echo %cd%` after, the `^` is still removed

Comment: Yes, try it with `echo !cd!`, as the percent expansion is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it twice - once when you input the path as an argument to the batch script, and again when echo'ing it:

**caret_input.bat**:

```
echo %1
```

Double-escaped (notice how it's already escaped when the batch file starts outputting):

```
C:\>caret_input.bat my\path^^^^is\special

C:\>echo my\path^is\special
my\path^is\special
```

If you were to use a string with a special character inside the batch file, your method of escaping it just once would work just fine:

**caret_escape.bat**:

```
echo my\path^^is\special
```

and the output

```
C:\>echo my\path^is\special
my\path^is\special
```

Comment: IMHO the content should be *clean* in the sense that it shouldn't contain extra carets to handle percent expansions, as it gets nasty to handle situations when you try to use it also with quotes. In the most cases delayed expansion is the right choice here