# What is a command that will write a command to a file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to make a batch file that writes a command to a batch file. I have tried using

```
@echo "@echo this is a test>test.txt">testBat.bat
```

Which gives me the output in testBat.bat of:

```
"@echo this is a test>test.txt"
```

This issue is, it still has the quotations around it in the batch file, and running it without the quotes gives me:

```
"this is a test"
```

So running it without the quotes just puts the text in the batch file. And after spending a half an hour looking I couldn't find if this was at all possible.

Comment: [Escaping characters like ", <, >, >>, or | in the arguments to a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32414436/995714), [Batch character escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6828751/995714), [Escape percent in bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13551829/995714), [Escape special character in a windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32817929/995714), [Special Characters in Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37333620/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo @echo this is a test^>test.txt>testBat.bat
```

I vaguely remember that cmd uses `^` as an escape character.