# Special Characters in Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping

Special characters in batch files are a pain, but I haven't found the right workaround for properly escaping the first two characters of this particular string I'm trying to pass the application.

```
SET pass=^&AntiBatchfileString
A_Program.exe /pass=%pass%
```

Things I have tried:

```
:: Escaping the escape twice, first for ^, second for &.
SET pass=^^^^&AntiBatchfileString
echo %pass%

:: Combining escapes.
SET first=^^
SET second=^^&AntiBatchfileString
SET pass=%first%%second%
echo %pass%

:: Preventing expansion
SET first=^^
SET second=^^&AntiBatchfileString
SET pass=!first!%second%
echo %pass%

:: I got this to print correctly
SET "pass=^&AntiBatchfileString"
echo ^^%pass%
```

Still when passing the last one it doesn't accept the login, I don't know what the final output is. That got me thinking maybe it was trying to do another expansion when passing the parameter to the application, so I quoted that as well.

```
SET "pass=^&AntiBatchfileString"
A_Program.exe "/pass=^^%pass%"
```

It's still not working, I'm not sure what I'm missing at this point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch character escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828751/batch-character-escaping)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Supposing you want the string `^&AntiBatchfileString` literally, this is the best `set` syntax, as most special characters (`^` `&` `(` `)` `<` `>` `|` and also the standard delimiters `,` `;` `=` <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>) lose their particular meaning as soon as ther are placed in between `""`, and the `""` themselves do not become part of the variable value:

```
set "pass=^&AntiBatchfileString"
```

This works only as long as the command extensions are on, which is the Windows default anyway (type `cmd /?` and see the `/E` option).

When expanding (reading) a variable like `"%pass%"` (with enclosing `""`), special characters are still treated literally.

However, as soon as you expand it like `%pass%` (no `""`), they get back their special meaning. So you have the following options:

1. Use `set "pass=^^^&AntiBatchfileString"`, where `^^` escapes the literal `^` and `^&` the literal `&` when reading like `%pass%`.
2. Enable delayed expansion (see `set /?` about how it works and `setlocal /?` or `cmd /?` about how to enable it), where the variable value is expanded (read) at a point of time where parsing of special characters has already been completed.

I prefer the latter approach, because no special escaping is necessary, and it can also deal with `"` appearing in the string value (even if unsymmetrically present).
By the way, `"` can also be escaped by `^"`, as long as this does not appear within unescaped `""`.

Nevertheless, `%` signs cannot be escaped like `^%` in a batch file, because percent expansion happens before escaping, but you need to double them like `%%` to get one literal one each, independent whether or not the string is in between `""`.
Note that on the console, `%%` does not work.

Finally, literal `!` are consumed by the delayed expansion feature when enabled, therefore you need to pay particular attention to those in case, by escaping them like `^!`, or also by intelligently toggling delayed expansion (hence to enable it only when it is actually needed and to disable it otherwise, when a literal string is provided, like in a `set` command line, for instance, when expanding a standard variable like `%pass%` and when reading a `for` variable like `%%I` (batch file) or `%I` (console), for example). Of course this is also not the ultimate solution, because you need `setlocal` and `endlocal` to enable/disable delayed expansion, which are intended to localise environment changes, so any variable changes since the most recent `setlocal` command are lost as soon as `endlocal` is executed (there are some tricks for passing a variable value over the `endlocal` barrier though).

Comment: Ah I see now, plus after fiddling with it so much I didn't realize that I left this part in `"/pass=%pass%"` while trying the other stuff. It's working now and thanks for the tips, @aschipfl!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use % as a string without escaping in a batch file:

Like %20, you can use `%%%20`.

```
git clone "https:// abc.com /D%%%220an"
```

Comment: Aren't 2 percentage characters enough in a batch file? Why do you have three here?