# How can I add greater than and less than into a batch file variable

Tags: batch-file

When I try

```
@echo off
set PTag=^<BR^>
echo %PTag%
```

I get nothing.

Now what's interesting is that if there's an empty line after the last echo, I get:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

If I remove the @echo off, then it actually outputs

```
echo <BR>
```

I want to add various HTML tags inside variables and then concatenate these variables to create an HTML that I will output in a file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`set PTag=^<BR^>` sets the value `<BR>` to `PTag`

When you run `echo %PTag%` it expands to `echo <BR>` which is an invalid redirection. You need to escape the `<` and `>` inside `PTag` by using this

```
set PTag=^^^<BR^^^>
```

The first `^` escapes itself, then the next one escapes `<` or `>`

You can also use this

```
set "PTag=^<BR^>"
```

---

Reason for the second way: inside quotes `^` loses its special meaning

> If it is a quote (`"`) toggle the quote flag, if the quote flag is active, the following special characters are no longer special: `^ & | < > ( )`.

[How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/995714)

> most special characters (`^` `&` `(` `)` `<` `>` `|` and also the standard delimiters `,` `;` `=` <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>) lose their particular meaning as soon as ther are placed in between `""`, and the `""` themselves do not become part of the variable value

[Special Characters in Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37336554/995714)

---

Now the variable will have the value `^<BR^>` inside it, and it'll expand `echo %PTag%` to

```
echo ^<BR^>
```

which is a valid command

Answer (score 5):

Just quote your `set`:

```
set "PTag=^<BR^>"
echo %PTag%
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you also add an explanation about the answer? I am not very good in batch, as it probably is obvious since I didn't know quotes can be used to wrap assignments. More precisely, I don't understand why the escape character works in quotes. When should one decide to use quotes around a command argument?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'm not entirely sure why, I just know it works :) Something about being escape characters, and being the line continuation character I think, this link might give you a better explanation http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Answer (score 2):

Just use Delayed Expansion when you show the variable value:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "PTag=<BR>"
echo !PTag!
```