# Batch - syntax error when trying to echo greater-then sign (>)

Tags: batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting

I have the following stript:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /A countArgs=1
...
SET /A countArgs+=1

CALL :error "!countArgs!. Argument ^-^> bla"
EXIT /B 1

...

:error
    ECHO ERROR
    ECHO %~1
EXIT /B 0
```

But the 2. `ECHO`-line in the `:error` routine `echo`s nothing. When I reduce the `CALL` argument string to `"!countArgs!. Argument ^-^>"` i get a syntax error and when i reduce it to `"!countArgs!. Argument ^-"` or even `"!countArgs!. Argument -"` it works properly.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43349607/5233188) the character should be escaped when adding a `^` if it is inside quotes which makes sense because when using the string as a parameter in the `:error` routine the `~` removes surrounded quotes...

How can i fix it?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no need to escape the `>` with the `call`. It's safe due to the surrounding quotes. The error occures when echoing it in the subroutine. You can use delayed expansion to `echo` it:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /A countArgs=1
...
SET /A countArgs+=1

CALL :error "!countArgs!. Argument -> bla"
EXIT /B 1

...

:error
    ECHO ERROR
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%~1") do echo for:      %%a
    echo quoted:  "%~1"
    set "x=%~1"
    ECHO delayed:  !x!
EXIT /B 0
```

It's safe with the `call` line because of the surrounding quotes.
It's safe with the `set` command, also because of the surrounding quotes.
It's safe with the `echo` because of using delayed expansion (`echo %x%` would fail, but `echo "%x%"` would be fine - although it will show the surrounding quotes).

Comment: Thank you, but is there no way to avoid the `set ...` and echoing it directly?

Comment: added another alternative.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the exclamation mark at the end does not get `echo`d but because the question was regarded to the syntax error in my previous approach i asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50419709/5233188) for that.