# Batch - How to echo exclamation mark inside string passed as parameter to subroutine?

Tags: batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting

I have the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /A countArgs=1

FOR %%p in (%pathListToCheck%) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST %%p (
        CALL :error "!countArgs!. Argument -> bla!"
        EXIT /B 1
    )
    SET /A countArgs+=1
)

:error
    ECHO ERROR  
    set x=%~1
    ECHO !x!
EXIT /B 0
```

Unfortunately the exclamation mark does not get `echo`d. I also tried to escape it like `^!` and `^^!` but it doesn't work.

I use delayed expension here to make the greater-then sign (`>`) work. If i would try to ECHO the parameter directly (`ECHO %~1`) it would fail. For details see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50418477/5233188)

How can fix this?

I appreciate your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't read/understand Stephans summary in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50419028/6811411).
`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is the cause of the vanished exclamation marks.
There is no reason to use it in your present code.

If you want to echo `<|>&` without qoutes you have to escape those. That can be done by code.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\19\SO_50419709.cmd
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

SET /A countArgs=1

set "pathlisttocheck=%userprofile%,x:\x\x\"
FOR %%p in (%pathListToCheck%) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST %%p (
        CALL :error "%%countArgs%%. Argument -> bla!  %%~p"
        EXIT /B 1
    )
    SET /A countArgs+=1
)
EXIT /B 1

:error
ECHO ERROR  
set "x=%~1"
set "x=%x:>=^>%"
ECHO %x%
EXIT /B 0
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\05\19\SO_50419709.cmd
ERROR
2. Argument -> bla! x:\x\x\
```

Comment: I edited my answer. Because I use a for-loop i need delayed expension. But I skipped it because i thought it would be unnecessary information. And of course I would also suggest that delayed expansion is unnecessary in the error routine but it is/was a working solution...

Comment: That's still no reason to use delayedexpansion, see changed answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you escape the exclamation mark and *dis*able delayed expansion *inside the function*, it works (although it removes the "delayed" alternative - which you didn't like anyway)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /A countArgs=2
CALL :error "!countArgs!. Argument -> bla^!"
EXIT /B 1

:error
  setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%~1") do echo for:      %%a
    echo quoted:  "%~1"
  endlocal
EXIT /B 0
```