# Batch - Won't echo a specific line to file

Tags: batch-file, escaping, echo, special-characters

I am trying to write some code to a VBS file through batch. Everything works fine except

```bat
echo if(Time()>TimeValue("8:30am") and Time()<TimeValue("3:15pm")) then >>
```

This is among other echos to this file like

```bat
echo do >> %APPDATA%\tbwg22f.vbs
echo if(Time()>TimeValue("8:30am") and Time()<TimeValue("3:15pm")) then >> %APPDATA%\tbwg22f.vbs
echo Dim message, sapi >> %APPDATA%\tbwg22f.vbs
```

The `if(Time)` line won't echo to my VBS file but all the other ones do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(`, `)`, `>` are [special characters to the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37333620/995714). You need to escape them to print as a literal string

```bat
echo if^(Time^(^)^>TimeValue("8:30am") and Time^(^)^<TimeValue^("3:15pm"^)^) then >>
```

Comment: You are an absolute legend, spent ages trying to solve this and couldn't find any info online