# Passing multiple commands to START command in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

I'm using [`start`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx) to run a command from a batch file.

```sh
SET mycmd=SOME_CMD WITH ARGS
START "Demo" %mycmd%
```

This works fine, and the resulting cmd window persists after executing the contents of `mycmd`, even if the batch file was double-clicked - the reason why I'm using `start` to begin with.

However I would also like to print something in the new cmd window that `start` opens, before it runs the command.

I'd imagine that I would pass start an echo command, followed by the command I want it to run.

My first naive approach was as follows:

```sh
SET mycmd=SOME_CMD WITH ARGS
START "Demo" ECHO Running Command... && %mycmd%
```

Of course this does not work; `start` opens a new window which only runs the `echo` command, and the command after the `&&` divider is run in the original window, not in the new one that the `echo` ran in.

Basically it performs `(start echo) && (my_cmd)` instead of `start (echo && my_cmd)` - *parentheses added for clarity, not any actual syntactic meaning*

---

So my question is: Is there a way to pass two commands to `start` at once? Specifically, I really just want it to `echo` out some content, and then run a command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch character escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828751/batch-character-escaping)

Comment: [Special Characters in Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37333620/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `&&` to `^&` to escape a single `&` which then cascades the `echo` with your command.

Comment: That accomplished the desired effect. Cheers!