# Use PowerShell variables in cmd command not working

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am having difficulty with executing a command line in cmd from Powershell.  The problem is I can't seem to use my global variables in the command line when cmd is opened from Poweshell.  Below is the code I am working with but to no avail.  Can someone please provide guidance on this issue?

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -verb RunAs -ArgumentList {/k set Name="$cmdname" set Item="$cmditem" setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion echo "%Name%" }
```

Thanks,
Roger

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082). And you can't just concat several commands on a `cmd` command line like that. It's `command1 & command2 & command3``

Comment: It would help if you were to explain your goal (so as to avoid the "XY problem").

Comment: `setlocal` won't have an effect when being executed in Command Prompt context (so in a command line in `cmd.exe /K` or `cmd /C`), it only works in a batch file. You could however use `cmd /V:ON …` to enable delayed expansion. Nevertheless, enabling alone is not enough, you also have to *use* it, like `!Name!` rather than `%Name%`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is awkward for sure:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/k set Name=$cmdname & set Item=$cmditem & call echo %name%"
```

Some of the reasoning here is:

- **cmd**: additional commands need to be separated by `&`
- **cmd**: the `set` command takes everything after `=` until [special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333620/special-characters-in-batch-file) like `&`
- **cmd**: `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` doesn't really [apply](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) here. Use `call` to delay instead.

  - delayed variable syntax is also `!var!` rather than `%var%`
- **Powershell**: using brackets in `-ArgumentList {stuff}` sends as a literal string, and variables aren't expanded

Comment: Instead of `call echo %name%` you should perhaps use `call echo %^name%` for the case a variable `name` is already defined in advance…