# Using loops to rename filenames with batch script

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, if-statement, findstr, blat

I have a a folder with the files: File1.txt and File2.txt

The contents of file1.txt are:

```
"DTS053C0 RUN DATE 10/01/11 DATATRAK SYSTEM PAGE 001
RUN TIME 13:35:08
INPUT PROGRAM TRANSMISSION STATUS REPORT
STATUS - INPUT RECEIVED BY DTCC'S DATATRAK SYSTEM
DETAIL RECORDS RECEIVED 0
HEADER RECORD RECEIVED
HDR.SSYSID.E00.CORIG.SSUBOMMDDYYYY HEADERFILEDESCRIPTION N001 *
REJECTED
NO MATCH ON EXPECTED MASTER FOR HEADER"
```

Contents of file2.txt are:

```
"The confirm file received from DTCC will be in the following format:
DTS053C0 RUN DATE 10/01/11 DATATRAK SYSTEM PAGE 001
RUN TIME 12:53:32
INPUT PROGRAM TRANSMISSION STATUS REPORT
STATUS - INPUT RECEIVED BY DTCC'S DATATRAK SYSTEM
DETAIL RECORDS RECEIVED 22
HEADER RECORD RECEIVED
HDR.SSYSID.E00.CORIG.SSUBOMMDDYYYY HEADERFILEDESCRIPTION N001 *
ACCEPTED
Example"
```

I am looking for a batch script to scan through the contents of these 2 files separately and identify the files which contain the word "REJECTED" and then send an email to my email-id like a notification saying "this file has been rejected, kindly check".

- I am using blat to send emails as notifications *

Comment: `findstr /m "REJECTED" file?.txt`

Comment: just the name(s)  of the file(s) which contains the string `REJECTED`

Comment: Fine. And what is your specific programming-related question that suits this site, according to the [tour]? Please learn [ask] here! Provide a [mcve] of your coding attempts and precisely describe what you having trouble with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wrap @Stephans suggestion into a batch:

- `Findstr /M` reports only file names which had a match on `REJECTED`,
- The `for /f` processes this output and the set gathers this in the
  variable Found. The first entry produces a leading comma.
- When finally passing this variable content as an argument to the subroutine
  :Blat this first comma is removed by substring `%Found:~1%` from 2nd
  pos (zero based)
- In the sub you can use `%*` = (all passed arguments) to have it as mail subject or body for your blat routine.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\14\SO_50858355.cmd
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Search=REJECTED"
Set "Files=file?.txt"
Set "Found="
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
  findstr /m /i "%Search%" %Files%
') Do set "Found=!Found!,%%A"
If Defined Found (
    Call :Blat %Found:~1%
) Else (
    Echo No files "%Files%" containing "%Search%" found
)
Pause
Goto :Eof

:Blat
Echo found Rejected in %1
If "%2" neq "" (shift & goto :Blat)
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_50858355.cmd
Yourblatcommand found Rejected in file1.txt
```

new sample output:

```
> SO_50858355.cmd
found Rejected in file3.txt
found Rejected in file1.txt
```

The batch file as is searches only in the current folder and with the wildcard `file?.txt` so you have to adapt the variables to fit your needs or first set anotther working dir.

Comment: Can u explain how this works "Call :Blat %Found:~1%" and "Echo.....in %*"

Comment: See changed answer with some more explanations.

Comment: I tried to run this code, but the cmd just crashes without anything happening.

Comment: Huh, what do mean with `crashes`? How do you run/start the batch. There are some geenral rules how to debug a batch. See this [answer from today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50858801/6811411) the rules apply here also. And [SO] isn't a script writing service, but a site where programmers help colleages to fix a distinct problem with their code. Since it's **your** task you should be the one doing research, find bugs and remove them.

Comment: Hey! It works perfect. 
If both the files have the word REJECTED then I am getting output as  "file1,file2 were rejected" 
How do I change that to "File 1 was rejected <return>
                                        File 2 was rejected" ?

Comment: The variable Found is passed to the sub unquoted with the commas in between file names. I used `%*` to have them in one  piece while it are really several arguments you can process one after the other using %1 and if %2 isn't empty shift and go back to the label :blat. I'll change the answer in a minute. It's up to you how to  integrate this in your blat sending routine.