# Create script with unresolved variables or script arguments (like "%~dp0")

Tags: windows, batch-file, io-redirection

In a backup-restore scenario, I'm trying to generate a helper from within a batch.

The helper just combines `restore.bat` and an argument of the form `state-%today%.zip` to allow a specific restore without opening a command prompt or drag and drop:

```
call restore.bat state-YYYYMMDD.zip
```

This way it can be easily generated by `backup.bat`. But the helper fails if it was run as administrator (which is the actual goal of the coupling) because due to the context switch the current work directory changes to `C:\Windows\system32` and that's why the helper's sibling file is not found.

This can be fixed by using `%~dp0` that returns the path of the helper batch dynamically. My hand-made solution works as expected:

```
pushd %~dp0
call restore.bat %~dp0state-YYYYMMDD.zip
popd
```

Since *`YYYYMMDD`* is determined at backup time. I now need to generate the helper dynamically from within `backup.bat`, the first approach is

*`backup.bat`*

```
set HELPER=restore-%today%.bat
echo pushd %~dp0 > %HELPER%
echo restore.bat %~dp0state-%today% >> %HELPER%
echo popd >> %HELPER%
```

but the result

*`helper-20210630.bat`*

```
pushd c:\users\me\test\
call restore.bat c:\users\me\test\state-20210630.zip
popd
```

...is not portable to other folders. How do I pipe `%~dp0` verbatim to the helper batch?

I found nothing in

- [Echo | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo)
- [Echo - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)

And the advice to escape `%` via `^` that I found in [batch-file - Echo output to file | batch-file Tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/batch-file/example/28272/echo-output-to-file) didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure this question has the potential to actually be reopened at some point. At least the title was too specific to attract readers (or search engines) so I changed it to better reflect my actual goal.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out by trial and error is that the percent sign (`%`) has to be escaped by doubling (`%%`).

*`test-path.bat`*

```
@echo off
echo %%cd%% : %cd%
echo %%~dp0 : %~dp0

set TEST_OUT=%~dp0test-out.bat

echo echo %%%%cd%%%% : %%cd%% >%TEST_OUT%
echo echo %%%%~dp0 : %%~dp0 >>%TEST_OUT%

call %TEST_OUT%
pause
```

BTW: above script can also be used to show the divergence of the current work directors between a normal start *as you* by double clicking or pressing enter on it, or via *context menu* → *Run as administrator*

---

The whole case now turns out to be just another variation of [*Escape percent in bat file*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13551829/2932052). But we all know that once you've worked out a solution, you suddenly find it everywhere.