# how to enter "%" sign from .bat file to adb via command line?

Tags: command-line, adb

I tried the usual command: shell input text and virtual keyboard input: shell am broadcast -a ADB_INPUT_TEXT --es msg "%", but none of these methods work, on the command line when running the .bat file "%" everything still not entered

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape percent in bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551829/escape-percent-in-bat-file)

Comment: `adb shell input text '%'` works as expected your problem might be somewhere else