# How do I escape ampersands in batch file function parameter?

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping

This is continuation on question *[How do I escape ampersands in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327431/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-batch-files)*.

That question presents some ways to use ampersands in batch files. However, it would seem none of those work for function parameters. Example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call:myFunction "http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=escape+ampersand"

goto:eof

:myFunction
echo Param is: %~1
goto:eof
```

I would always get

```
Param is: http://www.google.com/search?client=opera
'q' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried `^` to escape it and that doesn't seem to work either. Is there a way?

If it matters, my actual use case is supplying a download URL to wget which is called within a batch function.

Comment: I am also having the same problem, will apply your solution now and see.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim isn't it already explained in the beginning of the question why this isn't a duplicate? None of the answers there work by themselves - what was needed was quotes *inside the function as well*, not just in the original call.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read question properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feeling a bit silly now...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call:myFunction "http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=escape+ampersand"

goto:eof

:myFunction
echo Parameter is: "%~1"
goto:eof
```

Result:

```
Parameter is: "http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=escape+ampersand"
```

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: @SketchBookGames added quotes to my "Param is" printing

Comment: What if you don't want the double quotes printed, though?

Answer (score 1):

`^&` is the correct way to escape, but it isn't usually needed in double quotes.

Source: *[Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)*