# C++ odd thing with ampersand (&) in command argument

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, arguments, ampersand

I just found out something rather strange here. It wasted me the better part of a day.

In MSVC, when an argument passed to the main program is abc&123, if one runs the program using the "Start Debugging" option, MSVC will pass the argument (one of argv[]) as "abc&123". But if one runs the program using "Start Without Debugging", MSVC will pass only "abc" and cut off whatever after the "&". What is the reason behind this?

Comment: When run without debugging, you have to put `abc&123` in quotes `"abc&123"`, to stop the command-line interpreter processing the `&` sign.

Answer (score 2):

& is interpreted as a new command in your command line. nothing wrong with your code. OS interpret!

Create following code and test!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
        cout<<"arg "<<i<<": "<<argv[i]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

test followings in command line:

```
appname aaa& bbb

appname "aaa& bbb"
```

The first line is interpreted as two separate commands:

```
appname aaa
bbb
```

while the second one is only one command:

```
appname "aaa& bbb"
```

This is the mechanism defined in shell and OS from back to MS-DOS. Quotations change the order of tokens similar to parenthesis in mathematics.

**Update:**

The debugger does pass the variable from different process. It knows that & is not referring to a new command. Start without debugging is more accurate. You may call it bug in the debugger.

Comment: So why is it different when debugging?

Comment: No difference between running in command line or debugging. Ampersand separate the commands. This is problem of the other people too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327431/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-batch-files

Comment: The question is asking about this difference. You're not answering the question.

Comment: The confusing part is the different behavior between  "Start Debugging" and  "Start Without Debugging", when the code is compiled EXACTLY the same, with the win32 debugging configuration.

Comment: I think people are looking for the words "shell interpretation" somewhere in this answer.