# adb broadcast with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, adb, broadcast

i'm currently setup campain measurement testting

my pakage :

```
com.example.proj
```

and my reciver :

```
com.example.proj.reciver.Mreciver
```

cmd:

```
 adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.example.proj/com.example.proj.reciver.Mreciver --es  "referrer" 'utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign'
```

I does not work , but if i replace & character , it's ok .
What i'm missing?
Sorry for my bad english

Edit:
i have put 2 line :

`adb shell`

then

`am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.example.proj/com.example.proj.reciver.Mreciver --es  "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"`

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape ampersands in batch files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327431/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-batch-files)

Comment: if i replace & with ^& , it does not work