# how to use a "&" in node.js child_process exec command?

Tags: node.js, escaping, child-process

I am using child_process to launch software from Windows clients connected on my server. The general cases are working like a charm but in one I have a "&" sign which fails the command to launch.

Is there a way to escape this kind of special char ?

Here is a example of my command:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
child = exec('C:/Programs/program.exe /Callback:other&program.exe /Start');
```

There is one constraint: I cannot use /Callback:"other&program.exe" because program.exe is no to smart to escape the " signs

Comment: Try pass `/Callback:other&program.exe /Start` as options (array) to exec.

Comment: as you can see in [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), options is not used for command parameters but for exec specific options.

Comment: Yeah. Your answer is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327431/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-batch-files . Use `^` to mask ampersand `&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Aikon Mogwai said (thanks to him):

> Use ^ to mask ampersand &.

This is working for child_process exec command.