# Opening a URL with an equals in it

Tags: batch-file

I am looking to create a very simple batch file to open a URL. It's so simple I'm just using`start URL`.

The problem is that in the URL there are some '=' signs ie.`context=user&overlay=node` and this is stopping the batchfile from opening the full URL.

How can I stop this.

Kind regards

Matt

Comment: Have you tried to put the URL in double quotes? Like this: `start "" "URL"`

Comment: You could also escape characters to not being interpreted by cmd.exe with a caret `^=^|^<^>^&^,^;` as you see @Treintjes comment makes more sense in most of the cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape ampersands in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327431/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-batch-files)

Comment: As @LưuVĩnhPhúc notes, it's the ampersand that's causing the problem, not the equals sign.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably url-encode the equal signs to %3D - see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding.

Comment: The snippet the OP showed looks like they _need_ to be equals signs as they appear to be setting query values -- you would encode an equals sign if the _value_ contained an equals: `...&search=abc%3Ddef&...`.

Answer (score 1):

`&` and `=` are specials characters in batch scripting. Just quote the URL and pass an empty string as the title like that :

```bat
@echo off
start "" "https://example.com/context=user&overlay=node"
```

Comment: `=` is not a special character in batch