# Problem to get argument value when passing "&" character as value

Tags: python, weblogic, getopt, wlst

I'm using WLST to execute some scripts to deploy some applications in Weblogic.

I'm using getopt library in Python to parser command line arguments.

I created a script to download some files by FTP.

To do this, the user must inform the '**ftpurl**', '**ftpusername**' e '**ftppassword**' options and respective values.

---

```python
import getopt
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#=======================================================
# MAIN
#=======================================================
args = sys.argv
print 'Informed arguments: '
print args
for index in range(len(args)):
    if (":\\" in args[index]) :
        print
        print 'Removing arguments with file path'
        print args[index]
        del args[index]
        break
optlist, argsNotExpected = getopt.getopt(args, '', ['ftpurl=', 'ftpusername=', 'ftppassword='])
print
print 'Found options: '
print optlist
print
print 'Not expected arguments: '
print argsNotExpected
```

---

The argument value "test123!@#$%*()_-" that have many special characteres works.

```shell
java weblogic.WLST C:\\Ambiente\\scripts\\python\\getoptTest.py --ftpurl=ftp.test.com --ftppassword=test123!@#$%*()_- --ftpusername=usertest
```

**Result:**

```
Informed arguments:
['C:\\\\Ambiente\\\\scripts\\\\python\\\\getoptTest.py', '--ftpurl=ftp.test.com', '--ftppassword=test123!@#$%*()_-', '--ftpusername=usertest']

Removing arguments with file path
C:\\Ambiente\\scripts\\python\\getoptTest.py

Found options:
[('--ftpurl', 'ftp.test.com'), ('--ftppassword', 'test123!@#$%*()_-'), ('--ftpusername', 'usertest')]

Not expected arguments:
[]
```

---

But when I passing "test&123!@#$%*()_-" with "**&**" character, the value is break and the rest of the arguments are ignored starting from "**&**".

```shell
java weblogic.WLST C:\\Ambiente\\scripts\\python\\getoptTest.py --ftpurl=ftp.test.com --ftppassword=test&123!@#$%*()_- --ftpusername=usertest
```

**Result:**

```
Informed arguments:
['C:\\\\Ambiente\\\\scripts\\\\python\\\\getoptTest.py', '--ftpurl=ftp.test.com', '--ftppassword=test']

Removing arguments with file path
C:\\Ambiente\\scripts\\python\\getoptTest.py

Found options:
[('--ftpurl', 'ftp.test.com'), ('--ftppassword', 'test')]

Not expected arguments:
[]
'123!@#$%*' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
```

Can anyone give a tip?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the shell, since `&` is interpreted as a special character. In `bash`, it sends the command to the background, whereas on `cmd.exe` it's used to [chain multiple commands](https://htipe.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/multiple-commands-on-a-single-windows-command-line/).

This means you can't fix it in the script, but you can quote your arguments instead:

```
getoptTest.py --ftpurl=ftp.test.com --ftppassword="test&123!@#$%*()_-" --ftpusername=usertest
```

Alternatively, you can use `^&` to escape ampersands (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27960888/12833309)