# Opening local (file) URL with parameters in batch file?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, cmd, process.start

I want to open local file on Windows 10 with url parameters.

Opening webpages has been answered in several questions (ie [escaping amperstands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327431/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-batch-files)).

But **how to open local files**?

The following opens the file without any parameters:

```
start "" "file:///C:/test.html?par1=1&par2=test"
```

I have found that without using start it works, but I have no idea why:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "file:///C:/test.html?par1=1&par2=test"
```

Can anybody explain why it works without start and why does not work with start?

--**EDIT**--

So from the comments of Gerhard and Mofi I realized that the start command needs the [title as the first parameter](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) and then the executable with its parameters. So as they wrote it should have **""** after the start command like so:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "file:///C:/test.html?par1=1&par2=test"
```

Comment: Are you sure?`;)` Your examples are different. The one explicitly runs `chrome.exe` and the other just `start`s the file, where the latter simply `start`s the file with the default program you have associated with the file type. So to imply that start is not working is incorrect. Try `start "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "file:///C:/test.html?par1=1&par2=test"` as per the reference __"opening webpages has been answered in severarl questions.."__ does not apply at all here where the characters are double quoted, so you can remove the escape caret as per my example.

Comment: PS! if chrome is in the path, then you can just run it without the full path in the command with something in the line of:  `start "" chrome.exe "file:///C:/test.html?par1=1&par2=test"`

Comment: The caret character `^` escapes `&` for being interpreted as literal character if the ampersand is __not__ inside an argument string enclosed in `"`. `&` and `^` are interpreted as literal characters on being specified inside a double quoted argument string. For that reason `^&` is wrong in both command lines as the URL of local file with parameters is enclosed in `"`.

Comment: `start` uses the function [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa) to start the application associated with a file extension like `.html` or `.docx` or a protocol like `file:` or `http:` and pass the arguments used on `start` command line as arguments to the application. So the question is: Which application is associated with protocol `file:`? But there is special problem with protocol `file:` as it can be seen on comparing the file associations of `file:` and `http:` or `https:`.

Comment: The answer lies in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327444) you linked; you would have found it if you had read more than just the first two answers…

Comment: Run in a command prompt window `reg query HKCR\http\shell\open\command /ve` and `reg query HKCR\https\shell\open\command /ve`. It can be seen which application is associated with these two protocols. Then run `reg query HKCR\file\shell\open\command /ve` and an error message is output as there is no such key. Run next `reg query HKCR\file /s` and it can be seen that there is not much defined for protocol `file`. The reason is that `file` in registry is also for `file` as type of a directory entry like `Directory` (only directories) and `Folder` (directories and virtual folders).

Comment: But it is best to download and extract the free Sysinternals (Microsoft) tool [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to a directory of a local drive, start it, __add__ the two filters *Process Name is cmd.exe* and *Process Name is chrome.exe* (or whatever executable opens the local HTML file), run next in a command prompt window `start "" "file:///C:/test.html?par1=1&par2=test"`, switch back to Process Monitor, stop capturing with Ctrl+E and look on all the file system and registry entries from top to bottom.

Comment: If you double click in Process Monitor log on first line with `chrome.exe` in column `Process Name` and switch to tab `Process`, you could see that `cmd.exe` used `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "C:\test.html"` to start Chrome and pass the file name and only the file name without `file:///` and without `?par1=1^&par2=test` and with `/` replaced by ``\`` to Chrome. The reason can be seen above as `cmd.exe` tried to find out which file could be meant by the argument `file:///C:/test.html?par1=1&par2=test` for starting using Windows File I/O functions.

Comment: Please read the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) for an explanation why `cmd.exe` splits up `"file:///C:/test.html?par1=1&par2=test"` on its approach to find an executable or script file with valid full qualified file name matching the argument to start. `start` is designed for starting executables and for that reason `cmd.exe` tries everything it can do to really find a file which can be started before using `ShellExecuteEx`. That is helpful in most cases, but not in this special case.

Comment: You can use `start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "file:///C:/test.html?par1=1&par2=test"` in the batch file. If you want to open the local HTML file with the parameters in default browser associated with protocol `file`, you have to query the registry in your batch file to find out which executable is associated with protocol `file:` and use `start` with the executable file name and with `"file:///C:/test.html?par1=1&par2=test"` as argument for the browser executable.