# How to build a set-variable containing the ampersand as value?

Tags: batch-file

pre: I already looked at this, but it does not work in my case.
[How do I escape ampersands in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327431/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-batch-files)

In a (Win10) batch file for cmd, I get passed some arguments and I want to send them via WGET.exe %set_var% to my web server.

What i need is the resulting string for WGET in a set-variable which should read like:

<ipaddress&port>?p1=%1%&p2=%2%&p3=%3% ...

I tried to escape the & with ^ and wrote ^& everywhere the & should appear like this line:

set zzz="%wget_addr%?p1=%1%^&p2=%2%^&p3=%3%^&p4=%4%^&p5=%5%^&date=%date%^&time=%time%"

wget.exe %zzz%

But it does not work. The result is just a concettenation of the arguments, but my variables are missing.

What do I miss to code?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since `<`, `>`, `&` and `%` are all special characters in batch, please show us precisely the command you wish to generate, including typical values for each parameter (obfuscated if necessary)

Comment: Command line parameters are referenced as `%1` etc, not `%1%`. So your code tries to concatenate the first parameter (`%1`) plus a variable named `%^&p2=%`, then a literal 2 then the variable `%^&p3=` etc.

Comment: (by the way: your `&` are safe within quotes - no need to escape them)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stephan, I guess the %1% was my (major) error. I always thought if one wants to use the content of a var, the trailing % is needed, which obviously is only needed when accessing a variable.

Comment: the parameters (arguments) are not "normal environment variables" - they work different (see `call /?` for what you can do with them ("Modifiers")).